# System Tray Messages and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Hi",duration=5)
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\shaki\PycharmProjects\_ScrappingModule\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)


driver.execute_script("alert('Test')")
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
driver.get(url)
```

Selenium doesnot load any page, i thought it was due to losing focus because of the system tray message but i don't know what it is,

if i run the same process through debugge and line by line every thing will work fine, which idk why.

i tried .sleep.

Comment: You have commented out the line that loads the page? or is 'url' defined somewhere else? What error message are you getting (if any)?

Comment: @Sri problem was with the module, seems win10toast and selenium don't go hand to hand

Answer (score 0):

using another module, seems problem was with the module

```
from plyer import notification as notifications

notifications.notify(
    title='Here is the title',
    message='Here is the message',
    app_name='Here is the application name'
)
```